# Why would an AfterPageLoad event fire on a custom control that is not rendered?

Tags: rendering, xpages, custom-controls

I have an XPage shown below. On initial load of the XPage the custom control ccWFSCat1template is set to Rendered = false. However, in the AfterPageLoad of the custom control I have this code

```
sessionScope.ssCat1View = compositeData.cat1View;
getCategory(compositeData.cat1View ,"" , compositeData.targetDB);
```

when the XPage first loads the value ssShowControl is set to false but the AfterPageLoad event of ccWFSCat1Template has fired and ssCat1View has the value from compositeData.cat1View of the custom Control. I was assuming that if the control was not rendered that not of it's actions would be processed and that none of it's custom properties would be available. The SSJS getCategory in the AfterPageLoad of the Custom Control also fails because it does not have everything it needs to process the action. It was my understanding that if something had rendered = false that nothing within the block was loaded or available. I'm very confused.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:debug="http://www.openntf.org/xsp/debugtoolbar"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">

    <xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.ssShowControl = false}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
    <debug:toolbar defaultCollapsed="false" collapseTo="left"></debug:toolbar>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:panel id="panelData">
        <xp:table>
            <xp:tr>
                <xp:td>
                    <xp:button value="Display" id="button1">
                        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="panelData">
                            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionscope.ssShowControl = true;}]]></xp:this.action>
                        </xp:eventHandler>
                    </xp:button>
                </xp:td>
            </xp:tr>
            <xp:tr>
                <xp:td>
                    <xc:ccWFSCat1Template cat1DisplayRows="25"
                        cat1View="vwDemoSort" dataDisplayRows="10"
                        dataView="vwDemoData" rendered="#{javascript:(sessionScope.ssShowControl)}">
                        <xp:this.facets>
                            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1"
                                xp:key="viewBodyFacet" value="#{javascript:veData}">
                            </xp:text>
                        </xp:this.facets>
                    </xc:ccWFSCat1Template>
                </xp:td>
            </xp:tr>
        </xp:table>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you look at the [JSF Lifecycle](https://web.archive.org/web/20050306051827/http://www-128.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2/) (The original article is somewhere hidden after a developerworks reorg), you can see that *invoke application* is one phase before *render response*. The `rendered` property is only taken into account in the *render response* phase. Thus your code runs. Not what you would expect, but works as designed

Comment: Am going to have to look at loading the pages differently. Just wasted the better part of a day. Oh well live and learn.

Comment: You could check inside the event if the property is set

Comment: Tony McGuckin had a very good explanation on another "issue" on rendered vs. loaded here: http://oliverbusse.notesx.net/hp.nsf/blogpost.xsp?documentId=BDA#BCE

Comment: Thanks Oliver that makes sense. I have been using the Rendered property believing it actually performs like the Loaded property. So I think I can go back to my test and set the Loaded property instead of the Rendered Property and get it working.